# MYSQL force show as text in aview

Tags: mysql

```
CASE CONV(HEX(REVERSE(a.ID)), 16, 10)
  WHEN 0 THEN 'XXX'
  ELSE a.Data
END
```

Instead of XXX MySQL is showing 0x585858, why? How to convince it to display 'XXX'?

I'm operating inside a view.

Comment: well, what values do you have in `a.id`? Unless one of those values reverse/hexes/convs to a 0, you'll never get anything BUT `a.Data`

Comment: The question refers to the case of a.ID==0, but it also could assume other values between 0 and 20.